# Cannot install node / node relocation error

Tags: 14.04, apt, nodejs, curl

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr)

I get the following errors:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
$ node -v
node: relocation error: node: symbol _ZSt7getlineIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEERSt13basic_istreamIT_T0_ES7_RNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIS4_S5_T1_EES4_, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference
```

Another try:

```
# Download and setup the APT repository add the PGP key to the system’s APT keychain,
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
...
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Fetched 2'060 kB in 36s (56.6 kB/s)                                            
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kdenlive/kdenlive-stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kdenlive/kdenlive-stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/realtime.sunlight.wallpaper/rsw/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/realtime.sunlight.wallpaper/rsw/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Error executing command, exiting
```

Comment: Is your network ok?

Comment: Network is fine.